# Disable direct launching of a job

Tags: jenkins

I have two Jenkins jobs: JobA, which triggers JobB.

JobB should never be run except when it's triggered by JobA.

Is it possible to make it so that users cannot accidentally start JobB?

I tried enabling project-based security on JobB, and turning everything off, but I am still able to start JobB.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Conditional BuildStep plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Conditional+BuildStep+Plugin) with this condition:

[image]

It should solve your problem :)